# Difference Between Logit Models and Logistic Regression?

Tags: regression, logistic-regression

I know these two model has different equation, but I am not sure why people use logistic model instead of logit model and vice versa? What is the main reason behind it?
If my response variable is a decision variable(yes,no), which model would be better here and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [stats.idre.ucla.edu](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/), you'll see that it's the same thing:

> Logistic regression, also called a logit model, is used to model
>   dichotomous outcome variables. In the logit model the log odds of the
>   outcome is modeled as a linear combination of the predictor variables.

To expand on that, you'll typically use a logistic model to predict the probability of a binary event to occur or not. And yes, if your response variable is a decision variable (yes/no), you can use a Logistic Regression approach. Most often it will be useful to recode `yes/no` to `1 or 0`.

You're not mentioning any specific tools here, but if you're using R you can easily set up a logistic model using `glm()`:

```
model <- glm(outcome~X1+x2)
```

Here, `outcome` is your decision variable and `X1 and X2` are your predictor variables.

Comment: @Tashaho, no problemn! I had some problems with the ucla link. Did it work on your side?

Comment: @Tashaho, cool! Would you consider marking my suggestion as the accepted answer? I tend to forget to do that myself some times...